# Problems with ipfw Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, port-forwarding

I want to forward port 80 to 4000 on my mac so that when I try to access my computer from my phone (which is on the same Wireless LAN) I don't have to write `http://computers-ip:4000`. For some reason accessing 4000 does not work but 80 does.

I've found many questions saying to use ipfw to do port-forwarding like so:

```
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8080 tcp from any to any 80 in
```

http://www.abetobing.com/blog/port-forwarding-mac-osx-mavericks-port-80-8080-and-443-8443-79.html

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111978/osx-firewall-forwarding-ports-ignoring-non-local-requests

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37418/how-can-i-open-port-80-so-a-non-root-process-can-bind-to-it

However, I cannot get this to work. I've added the rule and it looks like so:

```
sudo ipfw show
00100      0         0 fwd 127.0.0.1,4000 tcp from any to any dst-port 80 in
```

... but it simply does not work.

Does anybody have ideas for troubleshooting?

Comment: You want to redirect port 80 to 4000? You said you can't access port 4000, but port 80 works. Probably the service is listening in port 80 instead 4000?

Comment: from another computer, I cannot access port 4000 but only 80. On my computer I can however access 4000. I later today managed to create a VirtualHost as reverse proxy in `httpd-vhosts.conf` that works. The `ipfw` never worked though.